Tkinter's Canvas - bad screen distance ""
I'm working on a paint app using Tkinter's Canvas
and recently I've been trying to get the undo/redo system in place.
but there's a crucial problem with the redo function.
it doesn't have some values to recreate the elements even though I've stored them in lists.
Here is a simplified example:
class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...

    def paint(self, event):
        if self.previous_point != [0, 0]
            self.line = self.canvas.create_line(..........)
            self.line_group.append(self.line)
            if event.type == tk.EventType.ButtonRelease:
                self.line_groups.append(self.line_group)
        self.previous_point = [self.x, self.y]
        self.line = ''
        if event.type == tk.EventType.ButtonRelease:
            self.line_group = []
        if event.type == '5':
            self.previous_point = [0, 0]

    def undo(self, event=None, custom_index=-1):
        items = self.canvas.find_all()
        if items:
            last_group, cords = [], []
            if self.points_mode.get() == 'drag':
                if self.line_groups:
                    line_group = self.line_groups[-1]
                    loop_range = len(line_group) + 1
                    for line in range(1, loop_range):
                        ind = line * -1
                        last_group.append(items[ind])
                        cords.append((self.canvas.bbox(items[ind])))
                        self.canvas.delete(items[ind])

                    self.last_items.append((last_group, self.dash_groups[-1], cords))
                    print(self.last_items[-1])

                    del self.dash_groups[-1]
                    del self.line_groups[-1]
            else:
                try:
                    self.canvas.delete(items[custom_index])
                    last_group.append(items[custom_index])
                except IndexError:
                    pass
    def redo(self):
        if self.last_items:
            last_line, last_dash, cords = self.last_items[-1]
            item_type = self.canvas.type(last_line[0])
            f_color, o_color = self.canvas.itemcget(last_line[0], 'fill'), self.canvas.itemcget(last_line[0], 'outline')
            width = self.canvas.itemcget(last_line[0], 'width')
            self.iterate_lines(last_line, (f_color, o_color), width, last_dash, cords)
            del self.last_items[-1]

    def iterate_lines(self, group, colors, width, dl_size, cords):
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        for index ,l in enumerate(group):
            print(l)
            '''+ always returning none on the lines!
            * doesnt work even when items are not deleted and just hidden'''
            cords = list(cords.values())
            x, y, x1, y1 = cords[index]
            print(f'index {index}')
            fill, outline = colors
            self.line = self.canvas.create_line(x, y, x1, y1, dash=dl_size,
                                                fill=fill, width=width,
                                                smooth=self.smooth_line.get(), outline=outline)
            self.line_group.append(self.line)
        self.line_groups.append(self.line_group)
        self.all_items.append(self.line_group)


    return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
        self._w, 'create', itemType,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance ""

This is very weird and can be the slightest error, but I've checked many probable "big" causes and didn't have luck
Aftermath: I've even tried to capture the values in their initial creation, even printed them and it all was going well, but I can't create that line with them

You pass an empty string instead of coordinates or width. Your code is not runnable. To answer the question, people need to test it and see the full traceback.
